# How to select July, 2018 dates after 1 week interval in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

how to select or find July, 2018 dates after 1 week interval in MS SQL Server 2008/ 2008 r2

[image: select a month dates after 1 week interval]

Comment: What doyou mean *"after 1 week interval"*? So, for today, it would be all dates from and including `20181218` to `20190117`? What have you tried so far to achieve your goal?

Comment: `strDate` sounds bad - hope that's actually a DateTime col.

Comment: So in a week you want us to tell you how to select the dates in July 2018?   or, I don't know, I still don't understand what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Add a row number using following:

`row_number() over (partition by [month] order by [date]) as rn`

and then

`select ... where rn % 14 between 1 and 7`